# Does a positive series guarantee the equivalence between Abel summability and normal summability

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Give a positive series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$, if it's Abel summable, that is, $\lim_{r \to 1}\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nr^n$ exists, does it follows that it's normally summable ($\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ exists). I'm not sure about it since in general Abel summability can not guarantee normal summability, while there are some methods seemingly correct to prove this proposition which I'll post below

1. Note first $r<1$, then
   $$\sum_{n=1}^N a_n \leq \sum_{n=1}^N a_n\frac{r^n}{r^N} \leq \frac{1}{r^N}\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nr^n.$$
   Now let $r\rightarrow1$ the right-hand side of inequality is bounded, then let $N \to +\infty$, we get the series $\sum_{n=1}^N a_n$ converge
2. We have
   $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nr^n=\sum_{n=1}^N a_nr^n+\sum_{N+1}^\infty a_nr^n.$$
   Now fix $N$ and let $r \to 1$ we get
   $$\lim_{r \to 1}\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nr^n=\sum_{n=1}^N a_n+\lim_{r\to1}\sum_{N+1}^\infty a_nr^n.$$
   Next let $N \to +\infty$ since the left-hand side converges plus it's positive series, it must follow that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges

So is the proposition right or wrong? (I'm motivated to think of this from the Fatou theorem in Stein's real analysis).

[image]

If it's wrong, where? And how to prove the corresponding part in Fatou theorem. If it's right, is it a new result since ever before I only have in my mind Abel summability can not deduce normal summability in general unless $a_n$ satisfy specific conditions.

Comment: If $a_n \geq 0$ for all $n$, then we *always* have $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n = \lim_{r\uparrow 1} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n r^n, $$ regardless of whether they are finite or $+\infty$. This is a direct consequence of the monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: @Sangchul Lee.To my surprise,there is a continuous version of monotone convergence theorem!? I only know the discrete version of monotone convergence theorem

Comment: It is true that the usual formulation of MCT is through limit of sequence, but recall limit of function can be characterized using limit of sequence. A relevant version of this formulation is as follows: Let $f:[0,1)\to\mathbb{R}$. Then $f(r)$ tends to $L\in\overline{\mathbb{R}}=\mathbb{R}\cup\{-\infty,\infty\}$ as $r\uparrow 1$ if and only if for any sequence $(r_n)$ in $[0,1)$ such that $r_n \to 1$, we have $f(r_n)\to L$. Using this, you can upgrade sequential limit to function limit.

Comment: Or, in this case, we may exploit the monotonicity and replace the $\lim_{r\uparrow 1}$ by a limit along a sequence $(r_n)$ such that $r_n \uparrow 1$.